# How to make Inner Join in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

students: sID (primary key), sName, sCode

grades  : gID (primary key), lname, lgrade, sCode

I try:

```
" SELECT sName FROM students INNER JOIN grades ON students.sCode=grades.sCode WHERE sCode='A3';"
```

It return all records from the grades table!!

Did I have to specify relations when I create the tables?

Comment: My be I have to use ENGINE=InnoDB? My code work fine In SQLite.

Comment: don't you get an error saying that sCode is ambiguous in the where clause?

Comment: maybe all your records in the grades table have sCode set to A3

Comment: If you don't show us the actual query, we can't really help

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for doing such a query is like below

```
 SELECT sName,students.sCode as code 
 FROM students INNER JOIN grades 
 ON students.sCode=grades.sCode 
 WHERE code='A3';
```